# Unity: How to make camera look at a point

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, rotation, quaternions

im currently working on an adventure and got stuck at this, hopefully someone can help me:
I want the camera to face a given point, the way i do it looks like this:

```
public void LookAtPosition(Vector3 lookPosition, float speed)
{
    StartCoroutine(LookAtTransformCorutine(lookPosition, speed));
}

public void LookAtPosition(Transform lookPosition, float speed)
{
    LookAtPosition(lookPosition.position, speed);
}

public IEnumerator LookAtTransformCorutine(Vector3 lookPosition, float speed)
{
    StopLookingAtMouse();
    Vector3 direction = (lookPosition - transform.position).normalized;
    Quaternion targetRotation = transform.rotation * Quaternion.FromToRotation(transform.forward, direction);
    while (Quaternion.Angle(transform.rotation, targetRotation) > 1f)
    {
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, targetRotation, speed);
        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(transform.forward);
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    }
}
```

but the problem is it only works, when the camera has a rotation of 0, 0, 0, 1

Answer (score 4):

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;

 public class LookAt : MonoBehaviour {
     public Vector3 target;

     // Update is called once per frame
     void Update () {
         transform.LookAt(target);
     }
 }
```

You just have to assign this script to the camera.
You can read more about this here: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html I couldn't test the code but it should most certaintly work.

Comment: This is not what i want, please read the code. LookAt just changes the quaternion in an instand, while i want a smooth lerp with specified speed.

Comment: You could easily lerp the input vector3 to the lookAt function. Also in your question you asked exactly what Hambalko answered to.

Answer (score 0):

```
public Camera cam; //You cam goes here
public Transform target; //you target goes here 
public void LookAtPosition(Transform lookPosition, float speed)
{
    cam.transform.LookAt(target);
}
```

Comment: Im not sure how to add the thingy with time but this should be a help you can work out from

Comment: Ok Cam = the camera in your scene

Comment: transform is the object u want to look ats transform

Comment: cam.transfrom.lookat makes the cam look at the target by turning around